# Restrict public access to files in google cloud php application

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud, app.yaml

I have deployed a php application to google app engine. The app.yaml file looks like below:

```
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /api
  script: api.php

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

As of now, I am able to access any file inside js folder using the url: project-name.appspot.com/js/custom.js. Any user should not be able to view content of the file by just typing the path in the url. I want to restrict public access to any of the files except index.html. How can we achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: How are those `js` files intended to be used? Embeeded inside HTML files? Referenced via links?

Comment: Hi @DanCornilescu, The js and css files are intended to be used via links like <script src="/js/custom.js"></script>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `js` files are accessed by links (by the browsers, transparently for the user, when rendering the pages containing those links) then **you can't really hide their links** - they will also be accessible if the user types the respective links directly in the browser.

What you can do however is to **restrict access to these links** to the authorized users only (the others will get permission denied errors).

If you're using Google's [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/users/) then all you have to do is configure access in your `app.yaml` file (see `login` row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appref#handlers_element) table), like this:

```
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
  login: required
```

If you're using some other authentication method then the only option I can think of is to **not publish** the `js` dir as `static_dir` (as static resources are served directly by GAE to anyone without even touching your app instance/code, like a CDN). Instead serve the `js` files through you app code, dynamically - just like you do with your `api.php` code. This way you can implement any access policy you desire for each individual file, on a per-request basis (for example by checking user login/session credentials according to your authentication method).